# field_widget_form call as a custom form

Tags: 7, entities

I want to call my custom field_widget_form with the use of drupal_get_form()
Is it possible to do that?
simple requirement .. I want to build a form where user enter the field value and that value should be store with the node but only one field value instead of all 30 fields.

Now i have created the field with custom code so how can i call this function field_widget_form() in that or any other help full alternative.

Comment: is there any chance you can update/re-phrase the question a bit. I believe I have the same the question, but can't tell, and the answer doesn't make sense to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a widget form, you can change it from another module with [hook_field_widget_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7), which requires Drupal 7.8 or higher.

```
function hook_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  // Add a css class to widget form elements for all fields of type mytype.
  if ($context['field']['type'] == 'mytype') {
    // Be sure not to overwrite existing attributes.
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass';
  }
}
```