# Creating Number fields (integer and decimal) manually in code for custom forms

Tags: 7, entities

I need to manually render a number field in Drupal 7 on a custom form. I have created the following field definition:

```
$form['num_seats'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Number of Seats'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#number_type' => 'decimal',
      '#field_name' => 'num_seats',
      '#element_validate' => array ('number_field_widget_validate'),
      '#field_parents' => array(),
      '#language' => $language->language,
      '#field_prefix' => '$',
      '#size' => 14,
      '#maxlength' => 12,
      '#default_value' => $location ? $location['num_seats'] : $node->field_workshop_num_seats[$node->language][0]['value'],
);
```

However submitting the form produces an error of the form:
"preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 14 in number_field_widget_validate() (line 391 "

If I use 'integer' instead of 'decimal' for 'number_type', it works fine.
I checked Number module's code and could see this is bcause of regex not being created correctly from field definition.

So my question is how can I manually render Fields outside of regular Drupal entity_type context (i.e. outside node/user etc. forms) in a custom form whose submission gets stored to a custom table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some googling and a bit of thought of how I've used stuff in the past. You're confusing a FAPI element with a Field Widget. They are not the same thing, [this has been discussed before on Drupal.StackExchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31311/why-are-field-widgets-not-form-elements). And is fully answered there in terms of why they are different.

I think your easiest solution is to create your own `#element_validate` function and not rely on the validate function provided directly by `number_field_widget_validate` -- but I would copy its guts essentially and create your own validate function from it. The preg_replace is failing because your FAPI element is not a Widget and has no `$field['settings']`. That's what I think is going on.

Comment: Yeah, it was appearing to me Field Widgets can't be used directly on regular Drupal forms as FAPI elements. BTW, I had a look at Number module's code and realized it expected 'settings' element in a field. I tried all possible combinations of specifying 'settings' and 'decimal_separator' inside it to somehow have number module recognize it and generate correct regex for validation but unfortunately did not work out.

Anyways, thanks for replying..

Answer (score 1):

I guess after 3 years something changed.
As I was able to add a decimal field without error as follow:

```
'location_crossing_mileage' => array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Mileage'),
    '#size' => 5,
    '#maxlength' => 12,
    '#number_type' => 'decimal',
    '#field_name' => 'location_crossing_mileage',
    '#element_validate' => array ('number_field_widget_validate'),
  ),
```

Comment: Yes, but notice the question was not about creating a **field**, but rather creating a **form** with Form API. There is no `#number_type` property in Form API. The title was misleading.