# Numeric field type in Form API

Tags: forms

I am trying to add a "number" field type to a form using FAPI:

```
$form['phone_number']['areacode'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => '---',
  '#width' => '30%',
  '#align' => 'center',
  '#required' => true,
  '#maxlength' => 3
);
```

I change the TYPE to "number" and the field doesn't get generated at all. The number module is enabled. I have implemented the following theme functions:

- `MYTHEME_form_element`
- `MYTHEME_textfield`
- `MYTHEME_container`

What could be behind this field not showing up when I use `#type = number` or `#type = number_integer`, etc?

This might have something to do with it:

[Creating Number fields (integer and decimal) manually in code for custom forms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45800/creating-number-fields-integer-and-decimal-manually-in-code-for-custom-forms)

However I actually want the type to render as "number" in HTML so smart phones show a numeric dialer

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

```
$form['my_element'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes' => array(
        ' type' => 'number', // insert space before attribute name :)
    ),
    '#title' => 'My number',
    '#required' => true,
    '#maxlength' => 3
);
```

Comment: What's not clear?
_"Numeric field type in Form API"_ is need?
Define attribute " type" (**with space**) in #attributes array with a desired value: number, date, color...
dirty hack

Comment: max length is not working

Comment: Why does it ned to have a space?

Comment: This leads to invalid HTML btw.: `<input type="number" type="text">`

Comment: You can now use `'#type' => 'number'`, in Drupal 8/9

Answer (score 7):

As noted by @fritzmg , the Number element is [included in core as of Drupal 8.0](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Number.php/class/Number/8.0.x).

For example:

```
$form['phone_number']['areacode'] = array(
  '#type' => 'number',
  '#title' => '---',
  '#required' => true,
);
```

Comment: There is an interesting option that is `#step` :
`'#step' => '.1'` allows a precision of 1 decimal : 0.1, 0.2, ...
`'#step' => '.01'` would allow a precision of 2 decimals like 23,23 or 56,76 etc

Answer (score 5):

You can install and use module [Elements](https://www.drupal.org/project/elements) for it.

Comment: This is the correct way to get a HTML5 number field.

Comment: `#type="numberfield"` is the correct way to adjust the field when using this module.

Comment: This module is already included in the core in Drupal 8. The correct way to create a number field is by using `'#type' => 'number'` (not `'numberfield'`) in the render array.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party. The problem is that theme_textfield (D7: `includes/form.inc` , lines 3924ff) hard-codes `$element['#attributes']['type'] = 'text';`.

You may wrap said call in a `if (!isset($element['#attributes']['type'])) { ... }` or wait for the patch https://www.drupal.org/node/2545318 to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

this is your code below..

```
$form['phone_number']['areacode'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => '---',
'#width' => '30%',
'#align' => 'center',
'#required' => true,
'#maxlength' => 3
);
```

please tell me what is ['phone_number'] , it's a container or not or its exist in your form or not and if you want to create custom field in your form then you should use hook_form_alter [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

like

```
  function mymodule_form_alter($form_id, &$form) {
 if ($form_id == 'form_id') {

$form['field_name'] = array(
 '#type' => 'textfield',     
 '#title' => t('title'),
 '#description' => t('Description.'),
 '#width' => '30%',
 '#align' => 'center',
 '#required' => true,
 '#maxlength' => 3
 );
  }
   }
```

hope this help you..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it working with invalid value for the **#type** field, however you can do something like that:

The form element:

```
$form['my_element'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes' => array(
        'data-type' => 'number',
    ),
    '#title' => '---',
    '#width' => '30%',
    '#align' => 'center',
    '#required' => true,
    '#maxlength' => 3
);
```

And implementing **theme_textfield**

```
if(isset($element['#attributes']['data-type']) && $element['#attributes']['data-type'] === 'number'){
    $output = '<input type="number" />';
}else{
    $output = '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing for a solution -- but what do you mean it won't work with an invalid #value???

Comment: Well if you don't put a valid value for the **#type** the form element won't be rendered at all, as you stated before.