# Add html5 input types using drupal form api

Tags: 7, forms

I want to add HTML5 number type textfield in the form programmatically. I am building the form using hook_form().
I tried adding the code:-

```
$form['field_price']['#attributes']['type'] = 'number';
```

But it isnt working.

Is there any other work around for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to using [Element](https://www.drupal.org/project/elements), and since `theme_textfield()` has a hardcoded value of type 'text', you may want to override `theme_textfield()` in your template.php. You can copy `theme_textfield()`, paste it in your theme's template.php and rename it, then make necessary changes. For example

(NB: I **HAVEN'T** tested this, so there may be some bugs):

```
function MYTHEME_textfield($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (isset($element['#attributes']['type'][0]) && $element['#attributes']['type'][0] == 'number'){
    $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'number';        
  } else {
    $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'text';
  };
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value', 'size', 'maxlength'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-text'));

  $extra = '';
  if ($element['#autocomplete_path'] && !empty($element['#autocomplete_input'])) {
    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.autocomplete');
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-autocomplete';

    $attributes = array();
    $attributes['type'] = 'hidden';
    $attributes['id'] = $element['#autocomplete_input']['#id'];
    $attributes['value'] = $element['#autocomplete_input']['#url_value'];
    $attributes['disabled'] = 'disabled';
    $attributes['class'][] = 'autocomplete';
    $extra = '<input' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
  }

  $output = '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';

  return $output . $extra;
}
```

This will hardcode as type `text` any element that does not specifically have a key `$form['field_name']['#attributes']['type'] = array('number');`

Answer (score 1):

Try [Element](https://www.drupal.org/project/elements) module. it adds advance html5 elements to your form.

Similar question is asked [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137080/numeric-field-type-in-form-api)