# Using an address field widget on a custom form and storing data

Tags: 8, entities

I have a `Subscription` custom entity and I would like to use the default entity form for administration tasks and a custom multistep form for the subscription process.

I added an [address field](https://www.drupal.org/project/address) to my `Subscription` entity and I would like to use the widget in one of the custom form steps.

I was expecting I could use something like `'#type' => 'widget_id'` plus some widget configuration, but it does not seem to be so simple as [this answer points out](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/31330/27987).

> a widget and a form element are two different things that are used in different cases; consider a widget a more specialized type of form element.

What would be the right approach then? In the [`field_attach_form` change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2225801) a comment suggests

```
$display = EntityFormDisplay::collectRenderDisplay($entity, 'default');
$display->buildForm($entity, $form, $form_state);
```

How do I get just my address field? Form display modes?

And then, how do I deal with validating and storing the data properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the $form array's elements by setting their **#access** property to *FALSE*.

The validation and storing should be handled by the form for the corresponding entity by itself.

Comment: Thanks, @rémy, I was hoping for a more explicit method. Altering a whole form just to get a field seems a bit of a work-around, but you may well be right about this being the _most proper_ method currently available. I will wait a few days before accepting your answer to see if we get some other ideas.

Comment: Thanks again. At the end I ended up using `$display->buildForm` and then restricting access with an admin permission check on some fields.