# Render drupal field widget in custom page

Tags: entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is displaying a working Field Widget Form on its own possible?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/is-displaying-a-working-field-widget-form-on-its-own-possible)

I have my module called mymodule.

In mymodule.module I have:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['mymodule/ship/%node'] = array(
        'title' => t('Shipment details'),
        'page callback' => '_mymodule_addr',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB,
        'weight' => 0,  
    );
    return $items;
}
```

I want to render the addressfield widget inside the page. Then I want to read form values.
Can you help me?

Comment: Is the address field an entity field?