# How to implement a multiple (AJAX) field collection with the FAPI

Tags: 7, ajax, entities

Background: I have a field colleciton containing two fields. This field collection is attached to a profile entity and its number set to unlimited.

I am currently retrieving this field from the profile form to use it a custom form.

I get the form array and it is displayed correctly, but when I click on the button to add another element, I got a popup displaying this error:

> EntityMalformedException : Missing bundle property on entity of
>   typefield_collection_item dans entity_extract_ids() (ligne 7663 dans
>   /drupal_project/includes/common.inc).

Anyone have a clue or hint of what is going on behing the scene ? Maybe a solution to solve this issue ?

Update: the form I am making is a ctools multistep form. I am opened to alternatives such as Dave Reid's multifield.

Comment: Can you show your code please? Very hard to debug code without seeing code

Comment: Form API does not work well with full-blown fields... to bad I don't know anything better

Comment: There is not much to be shown, it is just a profile form retrieved with drupal_get_form('user_register_form'). Then the field collection contains two term reference, but this is configured in the UI.

Comment: It must be a problem around field_attach_form_validate as the entity parameter is null, Surely got to override some handler/validation.

Comment: So I switched to multifield, because the overhead of field collection is quite hard to comprehend. Now I only got a problem when I need to dynamically add a field item to the multifield. Seems like it is because I am creating a multistep form with ctools and the form_state array isn't likely to be understood by field_form_get_state in field_add_more_js.

Comment: @B2F It's difficult to get a field API widget into a standard FAPI form, but it is possible - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/is-displaying-a-working-field-widget-form-on-its-own-possible

Answer (score 1):

So, I followed the answer in the other thread Clive linked and this did the trick:

```
  $profile = new stdclass();
  $profile->type = 'some_profile_type'; 
  field_attach_form('profile2', $profile, $form, $form_state, LANGUAGE_NONE);
```

EDIT: Well, this is fixing the issue because it enables the form to use its widgets. But it remains a problem, the button part of the array is passed in form_state as a value, and I have to delete it manually...

Comment: That's not exactly Form API - please either edit question title or include some words of explanation why it's good to choose different approach.

Comment: yes you are right, although this is working, I will unmark it as accepted, so this stays opened if somebody find a better answer.