# Add Brightcove field through form in custom module

Tags: forms

I'm using [Brightcove Video Connect 7.x-6.0-beta2](https://www.drupal.org/project/brightcove) module and I want to add field in my custom module.

I was tried with brightcove, brightcove_video and brightcove_field types and it is not working.

Example of my try:

```
  $form['something_page_settings']['something_media']['my_module_bri_file'] = array(
    '#title' => t("Brightcove"),
    '#type' => 'brightcove_field',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('my_module_bri_file'),
  );
```

Can someone help me to add this field?

Comment: What do you mean by "add field" (are you trying to add a field to an entity? Trying to use a field API field in a custom form? Something else?)

Comment: To use field API in custom form...I updated my qustion with example.

Comment: Gotcha - it's not easy (it was never designed to be able to happen), but it's possible. The duplicate has an exhaustive list of ways to accomplish it ([this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/is-displaying-a-working-field-widget-form-on-its-own-possible#answer-69245) worked best for me IIRC)