# How make a standalone field with no Entity or Bundle?

Tags: entities

I want to add a custom configuration form to my module; I don't know if making a custom schema is better or if I should make a standalone field and use its different field APIs to deal with the value.

Can I create a standalone field with no entity or bundle? If I can't, what would be the alternatives?

Comment: Every entity has at least one bundle, and every field requires an entity to attach to. You can "fake it" with a dummy entity to get all field API fields out on normal form API form, but it's messy. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/is-displaying-a-working-field-widget-form-on-its-own-possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [system_settings_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form/7) and how it is used by other modules to create a basic form and field for module configuration. It'll generally use variable_get and variable_set to get and store it's value.